# Adobe Flash Text On Multiple Scenes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, flash-cs6

So I am having a problem with multiple scenes and text showing up.

Essentially I didn't have any problems until I created a second scene. With one scene, setting text works fine, but the second I add in that second scene, my text stops showing up. Here's my code, I'm fairly new to flash and don't know what the heck is wrong with it. Is this a common problem or is this fairly new?

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, jump);

var goingUp = false;
var health = 20;
var score = 0;

stop();

health_txt.text = "Health: " + health.toString();
score_txt.text = "Score: " + score.toString();

function gameloop(e:Event):void{
    crate_mc.x-=20;
    if (crate_mc.x<-100){
        crate_mc.x = 650;
        score++;
        score_txt.text = "Score: " + score.toString();
    }
    if (jumpman_mc.hitTestObject(crate_mc)) {
        health--;
        health_txt.text = "Health: " + health.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean 'Scene'? Frame? Stage?

Comment: @ZuzEL There are scenes when you do designing in Flash CSx, these are IIRC separate `Stage` object. The proper solution is not to use scenes period.

Comment: If you are adding a new scene to main timeline, this IIRC makes Flash create another `Stage` object, which contains *another* set of MCs, and your current set of properties still point to the objects on the old stage, so your text is changed, but on the wrong text field. I'd say you should use local hierarchy of scene simulating objects and not use scenes in Flash.